# My Account page Back to My Orders link how to move after Order Information in magento 2.3.6

Tags: frontend, customer-account, sales, link, magento2.3.6

My Account Page Sales order invoice page Back to My Orders link how to move after Order Information in magento 2.3.6

> http://magento2.com/sales/order/invoice/order_id/22361/
>
> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/invoice.phtml

```
<div class="order-details-items invoice">
<?= $block->getChildHtml('invoice_items') ?>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="secondary">
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="action back">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getBackTitle()) ?> 
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/invoice.php

<?php
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 namespace Magento\Sales\Block\Order;

 use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

 /**
 * Sales order view block
 *
 * @api
 @since 100.0.2
 */
 class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Items
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_template = 'Magento_Sales::order/invoice.phtml';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
 */
protected $httpContext;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_paymentHelper;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data);
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Order # %1', $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId()));
    $infoBlock = $this->_paymentHelper->getInfoBlock($this->getOrder()->getPayment(), $this->getLayout());
    $this->setChild('payment_info', $infoBlock);
}





/**
 * Return back url for logged in and guest users
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBackUrl()
{
    if ($this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/history');
    }
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/form');
}

/**
 * Return back title for logged in and guest users
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getBackTitle()
{
    if ($this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
        return __('Back to My Orders');
    }
    return __('View Another Order');
 }


}
```

[image]

Comment: share screnshot

Comment: check screnshort @Himanshu

Comment: Back to My Orders link in move after order information label ??

Answer (score 0):

Add code custom theme in magento 2.3

> ```
> Magento-Sales/layout/sales_order_invoice.xml
> ```

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!--
 /**
  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 -->
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice" name="back.order.invoice.url" template="Magento_Sales::order/invoice/back-url.phtml" after="sales.order.info"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> Magento_Sales/order/invoice/back-url.phtml

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
<div class="secondary">
    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="action back">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getBackTitle()) ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```